# When do integrable functions have a primitive?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Studying hyperbolic partial differential equations, we arrive, in a certain calculation, to the following doubt: every integrable  function has a primitive?

If $ u_0 $ is integrable, then $ \exists v_0 $ such that $ \int_b^a v'_0 dt = \int_b^a u_0 dt $?

I think no, but maybe there is some theorem that determines when this holds. And maybe this theorem aplies to our case.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: For fixed $a,b$, there is a constant $C$ such that $\int_b^a C dt = \int_b^a u_0 dt$.  So perhaps you mean something more difficult.  Such as: there exists $v_0$ such that your equation holds for all $a,b$?

Comment: @Gedgar, yes, this is what i am trying, for all a and b. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar is correct.  We cannot arrange that $v_0$ is differentiable *everywhere*.  But we can arrange that is it differentiable *almost everywhere*.

If $u_0$ is integrable on the interval $[0,1]$, then
$$
v_0(x) = \int_a^x u_0(t)\;dt,\qquad 0 \le x \le 1
$$
satisfies $v_0'(x) = u_0(x)$ for almost all $x \in [0,1]$.  And therefore
$$
\int_a^b v_0'(x)\;dx = \int_a^b u_0(x)\;dx,\qquad 0 \le a \le b \le 1
$$

This should be found in textbooks which cover Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Many thanks for the help!